# Create custom distribution compatible with C++11 random header

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Is it possible to create a custom distribution besides the ones in the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library? I'd like to make a distribution that behaves (in interface) like

```
std::uniform_int_distribution
std::normal_distribution
...etc
```

By that I mean I'd like to do something like the following

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

// Is something like the following possible?
my_custom_distribution dist;
dist(gen);
```

It looks like the distributions must follow the [RandomNumberDistribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomNumberDistribution) concept. Is it possible to create a new type of distribution that "plays nicely" with the other utilities, namely the generators and engines?

Comment: Yes, you implement a distribution by implementing a type that conforms to this concept. Yes, this is enough to make it play nicely with generators and engines (no need to inherit anything or like)

Comment: I don't see why not, if your class implements every requirement of `RandomNumberDistribution`, then it must play nice with the other utilities, as every other distribution have the exact same requirements implemented.

Comment: Checkout the source of the many available random distributions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random

Comment: _"It looks like the distributions must follow the RandomNumberDistribution concept. Is it possible to create a new type of distribution that "plays nicely" with the other utilities, namely the generators and engines?"_ Yes, that's the whole point. That's why `<random>` defines generic components that rely on concepts and requirements on types, not on specific types and base class interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum requirements are:

```
using result_type = ?;
result_type operator()();
static result_type min();
static result_type max();
```

where `result_type` is some unsigned integral-like type.  This is "UniformRandomBitGenerator" concept.

Most C++ `<random>` distributions also satisfy "RandomNumberEngine".

See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UniformRandomBitGenerator) or the standard for more details.

Comment: I think min and max should be declared constexpr static result_type to enable all desired functionality.